# Describing the topology of "Alexandroff" compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(A(X)=X\cup \{\infty \},\tau ')$ be two topological spaces. 
I've seen two ways of writing the topology of the Aleksandrov compactification.
$$\tau' =\tau \cup \{A(X)\setminus C\mid C \text { is compact in }X\}$$
$$\tau' =\tau \cup \{(X\setminus C)\cup \{\infty\} \mid C \text { is compact and closed in }X\}$$

**Thoughts:** Firstly I notice that the following set identity holds $$(A\cup B) \setminus C=(A\setminus B ) \cup (B\setminus C)$$
Hence, $(X\cup \{\infty\})\setminus C=(X \setminus C) \cup (\{\infty\}\setminus C)$ and since $\{\infty\}$ and $C$ are disjoint it follows that $(X\cup \{\infty\})\setminus C=(X \setminus C) \cup (\{\infty\})$.

**Question:** What I didn't understand is how to compare the requirements for $C$.

**Note:** Alexandroff isn't transliterated correctly. One should write Aleksandrov (from Александров) so please do not interpret this as a typo. Sadly most of the russian names in the mathematical literature are transliterated incorrectly.

**Added:** These definitions are indeed the same if we require $X$ to be Hausdorff. It follows from the fact that a compact subset $A \subset X$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is closed. Usually, when one studies this topic one reaches the conclusion that if we have a topological space $X$ that is locally compact and Hausdorff (but not compact) then the Aleksandrov compactification is unique up to homeomorphism and turns $X$ into a compact and Hausdorff space while preserving the fact that $X$ is homeomorphic to the subspace $A(X)\setminus \{\infty\}$. In this context clearly both definitions work.

Comment: The first definition is (generally) not correct. $C$ is additionally assumed to be closed in $X$. Note however that for Hausdorff $X$ it doesn't matter since a compact subspace of Hausdorff space is closed. BTW the $\iff$ is not true. Closed subsets of locally compact spaces need not be compact (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @freakish Now everything is clear. The first definition was given at my lectures and makes sense since we indeed require $X$ to be Hausdorff. The $\iff$ is indeed incorrect and I shall delete it.

Comment: Unrelated comment — do you know of a reference for the correct transliterations of names of well-known Russian mathematicians? (Perhaps I should ask this in a separate question/check if there’s one been asked...)

Comment: Short answer: You only need a table that gives you the bijective correspondence between latin and cyrillic russian alphabet.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian#Transliteration_table. Note that the "official" transliteration has changed over time. By official I mean what the Russian Federation aproves for transliteration names in passports. I could perhaps develop a bit more in a more suitable situation. One flagrant example is Tikhonov (usually Tychonoff).

Comment: The transliteration of Alexandroff and Tychonoff was based on the French practice at the time, and these authors published in French (and German too) , hence these transliterations.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: This surely should be a separate question as it has nothing to do with compactifications of topological spaces. However, keep in mind that it has good chance of being closed  as "opinion-based". My personal take on this is that one should ask though who are still alive how do **they** prefer their names to be spelled; as for the deceased, I try to use the spelling most common in my area of math.

Comment: @MoisheCohen yes, the “opinion-based” factor is one reservation I had over asking a new question. (Another would be that the question isn’t *really* about math, and perhaps should be asked in a different SE.) In any case, my curiosity has been sated by the next two comments and the latter half of your comment, so I don’t think this is a question I’ll be asking anywhere soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct general definition is $C$ should be closed and compact, because the idea of a compactification like $\alpha X$ of $X$ is that $X$ *as a subspace of the compactification $\alpha X = X \cup \{\infty\}$* has the same topology as $X$ originally had. This means that $(X \setminus C) \cup \{\infty\}$, which is the “new”  kind of open set we introduce for $\alpha X$ should obey the property that $((X \setminus C) \cup \{\infty\}) \cap X =X \setminus C$ is already open in $X$, or else the subspace topology on $X$ from $\alpha X$ would be strictly finer than the topology on $X$ we started with. This thus implies that $C$ should be closed (as well as compact, which is needed to make $\alpha X$ compact).

We lose nothing by this, because in the most common case where $X$ is Hausdorff the condition is redundant, and the subspace property holds anyway, but for general spaces where compact sets need not be closed, the distinction matters, because otherwise we don’t have a compactification in the sense that we do not change the topology on $X$.